# Single-Window-UI not possible?

Tags: windows, interface

I'm still very frustrated about the separation of the menubar (File, Edit, Insert, ...) and the open notebooks in different windows. I would prefer to have the menubar directly above each notebook in the same window, following the "normal" user interface principles of Windows and resulting a minimum of one window after startup instead two ones.

Is there any command argument or preference option I didn't find so far?

Comment: Switch to Linux !

Comment: Actually, I prefer the current method. In a multi-monitor setup it is much easier to spread your open Mathematica windows over the various monitors. I have always cursed Excel for not easily allowing this.

Comment: Well, I'm using Gentoo Linux in most cases... but I need the same window behaviour from Qt now on Windows. And switching - to be honest - to Gentoo on my ThinkPad is not proper solution, because I dont want to handle all the modules required by the different hardware (Wacom panel, 3G, and so on...). =)

Comment: @triton You could install Linux in a virtual machine. I bought VMWare workstation and then on my Windows Laptop I can have Fedora Linux or whatever. I mostly use Windows though for Mathematica if I need notebooks. It seems more stable.

Comment: Once a time when problems happened in my Windows, the menu bar was minimized. So I guess it might be able to be realized on an OS level? Anyway I'm looking for a solution too.

Comment: This is fixed in Mathematica 10.

Answer (score 4):

The recently relased Version 10 of Mathematica for Windows implements such a "normal" user interface with the menubar directly above each notebook in the same window.

Answer (score 3):

This is *finally* fixed in Mathematica 10!

Comment: SWB: I undeleted your answer and voted for it.  If the community welcomes Reiner Martin's answer it should welcome this one too.  I feel that both fall into a gray area where they do not directly answer the question itself but they both provide information that solves the problem for those willing and able to upgrade.